# What hash type is used by DISM / SFC?

Tags: windows, hashing, dism, sfc, winsxs

What hash type is represented below?

Example 1: 0h+p0j3/Y9s1ly0mqtU741bzLjqz12mDQGKtVScMeKg=

Example 2: uNryI5MYSV5U5O1NuFPGYexSxm2nLFrRXVqga+nQjw4=

These hashes came from the CBS.log file after running Window's DISM utility. Here's the full line:

```
2017-03-11 20:46:08, Info                  CSI    00000005 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-c...appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.206_sr-..-cs_8caf1c5c152c5f9f\resources.sr-Latn-CS.pri do not match actual file [l:24]'resources.sr-Latn-CS.pri' :
  Found: {l:32 0h+p0j3/Y9s1ly0mqtU741bzLjqz12mDQGKtVScMeKg=} Expected: {l:32 uNryI5MYSV5U5O1NuFPGYexSxm2nLFrRXVqga+nQjw4=}
```

It resembles Base64 but that can't be it, because the hash is always the same length with different size files. I also thought maybe it's not the hash itself, but the Base64 of something like MD5 or SHA, but Base64-decoding this string also doesn't help.

Thank you.

Comment: Base64 is just a way of representing arbitrary binary as text, in a form more compact than spelling out bytes as hex. You can't "decode" it into anything recognisable because there's no "string" to decode to; you just get the raw data of the hash back. If you Base64-decode it into raw data and then encode the data as hex chars, you'll get the 'typical' representation of a hash that you might be familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses SHA256 for hashing files in WinSxS:

```
<dsig:DigestMethod xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
```

Here is the content for the `FlashUtil_ActiveX.dll`:

```
<file name="FlashUtil_ActiveX.dll" destinationPath="$(runtime.system32)\Macromed\Flash\" sourceName="FlashUtil_ActiveX.dll" sourcePath=".\" importPath="$(build.nttree)\adobe\flash\">
    <securityDescriptor name="WRP_FILE_DEFAULT_SDDL" />
    <asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <dsig:Transforms xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
      <dsig:DigestValue xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">22R1ba1WE7oyGXwA0vGwywUOw/Hw/27MqRmwHJpL04g=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </asmv2:hash>
  </file>
```

Under `dsig:DigestValue` you see the expected hash. If Windows scans the files it creates the hash for the actual file and compares it to this hash in the manifest files in WinSxS.